# PLSQL Procedure with forloop and contains check

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

What I try to do is: To implement a custom merging procedure for 2 Signals into a a result signal.

**Start with rs = s2.** Copy all custom fields from SIGNAL1 into RESULTSIGNAL that are not present in SIGNAL2 (i.e. no custom field with the same ID present).

`"custom_fields"` in `SIGNAL_STRUCT` is a type of custom_fields_table

My Procedure siganture looks like this

```
 PROCEDURE signal_merge(s1 IN SIGNAL_STRUCT, s2 IN SIGNAL_STRUCT, rs OUT SIGNAL_STRUCT)
```

My pseudo code to achieve this is:

```
for custom_field : s1.custom_fields
    if(custom_field.cf_id  NOT CONTAINS IN s2.custom_fields)
       rs.custom_fields  ADD s1.custom_field
```

I cant find the right syntax for it. Can some one show me how I can implement this?

**Update: As Requested in comments**

```
create or replace TYPE SIGNAL_STRUCT AS OBJECT
id                        NUMBER (38),
emission_type             NUMBER(19),
custom_fields             custom_fields_table


create or replace TYPE custom_fields_struct FORCE
AS
OBJECT
(
field_id VARCHAR2 (128 CHAR),
field_value NUMBER (1)) FINAL ;

create or replace TYPE custom_fields_table FORCE
IS
  TABLE OF wf_bool_custom_fields_struct ;
```

**Update: Example**
S1 has custom fields

- "f1"
- "f2"

S2 has custom fields

- "f3"
- "f4"

First Step: rs = s2 
Second Step: run merge

Result: The custom fields table of result signal (rs) must have after merging

- "f1"
- "f2"
- "f3"
- "f4"

Comment: no one knows what SIGNAL_STRUCT is - can you share the DDL for that user defined type in your question(s) ?

Comment: Is this to be used to work out which rows in table1 need to be added/updated in table2 by any chance? Because if so, this is not the approach I would take - instead, I'd be looking to use a single `MERGE` statement to do the work in one go.

Comment: It would help to include the DDL for the dependent collection and object types too. Sample data and expected results would be useful too. It isn't really clear what you are trying to do, but for this part you seem to be trying to merge between nested tables - so you might want to look at the [multiset operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Multiset-Operators.html)

Comment: Thanks for adding DDL for SIGNAL_STRUCT, now please add DDL for custom_fields_table, and any other custom types.